# Why jQuery toggle direction "up" doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have this dropdown menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/dTLpX/

the problem is that the toggle direction from top to down effect doesn't work.

```
$(elem).find("ul").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, "slow");
```

I tried to change direction to down, up, top and bottom but doesn't work. 
Why?

where I went wrong?

Comment: toggle has been deprecated after jquery version 1.8

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam the [toggle event handler](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) not the [toggle(show/hide)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method

Comment: Have you looked into `slideToggle()`? In your case it would be `$(elem).find("ul").slideToggle(1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `toggle()` method properly. Have a look at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

If you want to slide your objects you are probably looking for `slideToggle()`, which only goes up and down by the way.

Keep also in mind that in your code you are calling `deactivateAll()` which will hide the menu every time a menu is clicked (including the same open one), then you call `toggle()` again on that element which will make it show again...

Try this fiddle see if it's what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/dTLpX/9/

Comment: That API goes out the window when using jQuery UI.